# what naming convention is recommended for modules containing client code?

Tags: maven, module, dependency-management

I am developing an HTTP API server in Java in a module called `<api-name>-server`.

For the convenience of the clients, I would like to develop a client module, `<api-name>-client`. The client module will handle all of the HTTP method calling and stuff like that. I am hoping this will also simplify testing a bit if we have a library in place to call the API endpoints.

In addition to its core model classes, the server package also defines classes meant to represent the model for JSON serialization. I would like to move these serialization classes, and possibly some other stuff, into a separate module that both the client and server libraries can depend on. The structure may look like this:

```
myapi
    server
        // core model
        // persistence back ends
        // HTTP controllers
        // etc.

    client
        // utilities for calling server endpoints

    ???
        // model classes for serialization. In general, there is a 1:1 mapping
        // between these classes and those in the core model, but there doesn't
        // have to be.
```

This shouldn't be too difficult, but I am wondering if anyone knows of any conventions to use when dealing with this scenario. What should the 3rd module be named? Although I am asking specifically for naming advice, other advice is also welcome.

Comment: Really asking for a name of your library which has a domain which is developed by yourself ? How should someone of us know a good name for it? Simplest is `model`?

Comment: Maven has naming conventions for everything - e.g. module-root/src/test is the root for unit tests. I am asking if there is a convention for naming a location for 'exported' or 'external' classes. In fact, I have seen projects with directories like 'ext', I think for this purpose.

Comment: I am not asking for you to name my library or my API for me.

Comment: Ok Ok..sorry misunderstanding on my site the intention of the question...but in this case it's up to you to name the module what fits best from your point of view...Apart from that if find out later it does not fit ...rename it...What you can do is to separate interfaces into a separate module like ´*-api` and the appropriate implementation like ´*-impl´... ? But if there are projects with directory `ext` it sounds wrong..or are we talking about and package named like that?

Comment: Thanks for hearing me out - I meant more like a package called `ext`. I am going with something like what you suggested - an `api` module which provides interfaces (and some default implementations).

Comment: I recommend to separate interface (api module) and implementation really...in consequence it could happen that you have a api module with only a single interface...but that's ok...